# Select, insert, cut, paste on all worksheets gives an error

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am tyring to loop this vba execution to all worksheets. Apparently, it only manage to work on the currently active worksheet. It was not able to repeat this for the other worksheets. Why?

```
Sub adjustcolumns1()
 Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Columns("B:B").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("H:H").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Columns("J:J").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Columns("H:H").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Columns("J:J").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "select" on sheets that are not visible... but your don't want to "select" anyway, that's a bad habit learned from not editing your recorded macros.  So lets adapt your macro to send the commands directly to the ranges desired without selecting, then tie those commands to a loop of worksheets.

```
Option Explicit

Sub AdjustColumns1()
Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Columns("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        ws.Columns("D:D").Copy ws.Range("B1")
        ws.Columns("D:D").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        ws.Columns("H:H").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        ws.Columns("J:J").Copy ws.Range("H1")
        ws.Columns("J:J").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Next ws

End Sub
```

And we can really shorten that even more:

```
Option Explicit

Sub AdjustColumns1()
Dim ws As Worksheets

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Columns("C:C").Cut
        ws.Columns("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        ws.Columns("J:J").Cut
        ws.Columns("I:I").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Jerry. I am new to vba. Appreciate your sharing. This helps.